# Angular5, Openlayers5 make your popup(overlay) draggable

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, overlay, openlayers, draggable

I am trying to make my popup draggable. I have seen some solutions with older openlayers versions but these wont work with the new version.

Map:

```
this.map = new OlMap({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new OlTileLayer({
      name: 'maplayer',
      source: new OlXYZ({
        url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=',
        title: 'maplayer'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: this.view
});
```

Popup:

```
this.popup = document.getElementById('popup');

    this.incidentOverlay = new Overlay(({
      element: this.popup,
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
      },
      autoPanMargin: 250,
    }));
```

what is the best way to make my overlay draggable

thx a lot

Comment: Does this help you : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/translate-features.html ?

Comment: @Askirkela I also saw that example but when is expirement with it in angular5 it says that new Select() does not have a constructor In angular I am using the OL module. Now I am a little bit stuck

Comment: You can pass options when creating a Select instance (look in the docs). Keep in mind that the latest types for the ol packages are not all up to date.

Comment: @Askirkela do you have an example of how i can fix this in combination with angular5?

Comment: why not upgrade to 7? https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples

Comment: @Knostradamus is an update easy from 5 to 7 ? and still the dragdrop will not be done bij openlayers

Comment: It's not hard: https://update.angular.io/ Just follow the guide. If your popup overlay is an Angular Material Dialog then this should be easy. Not familiar with openlayers. Got out of GIS a long time ago.

Comment: To initialize your Select, take a look here : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html .  Since an overlay is a feature, selecting it then translating it should work

Comment: Thx @Knostradamus i will try it

Comment: Thx @Askirkela I will take a look a that also

Comment: @Askirkela I tried a couple of things it really does not want to work so I need a example because the documentation is not very clearly there are no examples

Comment: Do your users HAVE to be able to translate your overlay or could you do it programmatically? If you can do it programmatically, use the `Overlay.setPosition([number, number])` (in your layer's projection) to move your overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the ol/interaction/DragOverlay of the [ol-ext lib](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext).

An example is avaliable here: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.dragoverlay.html

Comment: can we also make a part over the overlay clickable

Comment: when I start dragging the popup directly switches position also in the example you send me. any idea of how i can set the point where there is clicked of the popup as the point from where the dragging has to start?

Comment: The popup is located on its anchor point at the cursor position.